# Windows 7 Dynamic Mirror Fails Redundancy

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, software-raid, mirroring

I have two 1TB HDDs forming a single volume in Windows 7 with a "Mirror" layout and a "Dynamic" type. The status is "Failed Redundancy" according to the Disk Management tool in the control panel.

What does that mean and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

> [**A mirrored volume's status is Failed Redundancy.**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787481%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_12)
>
> **Cause:** One or both of the members of the mirrored volume has failed, and the volume is no longer fault tolerant. To avoid data loss, you should attempt to repair the volume as soon as possible.
>
> **Solution:** If the dynamic disk's status is **Offline** or **Missing** (it cannot be accessed at all), an icon **(X)** appears in the graphical view of the Missing or Offline disk. For instructions describing how to repair the mirrored volume, see [Reconnect the disk and repair the mirrored volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758072(v=ws.10).aspx).
>
> If the disk's status is **Online (Errors)**, an icon **(!)** appears in the graphical view of the disk. For instructions describing how to reactivate the disk, see [Reactivate a mirrored volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786839(v=ws.10).aspx).